# TFS: Building solutions with different flavors (Debug/Release)

Tags: tfs

I'm using TFS 2008 and I would like to build some solutions in debug mode and some in release.

In my script, the section responsible to the 'build flavor' is global to the entire script and not for specific solutions...

There must be some way of accomplishing that... Can someone help me out please?

Thanks!

Comment: Please, can you give more details about the script. Perhaps a snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy way (that I know of).  The simplest workaround is to build for each configuration across all of the solutions in the build script.

Not ideal, but it should work.